# Client-side calls code-behind every 5 seconds in ASP.NET Web Form

Tags: asp.net

I'm creating a meteo page where the actual weather conditions are displayed.
For this I need a label to be updated every 5 seconds. I don't know if this is something that's possible with webforms, since I want to change its value after the page is loaded. I can load the initial value with the code in the page_LoadComplete event, but when I try to loop it, it doesn't update the label text.

Thanks

Code:

```
    public Wind Icarus = new Wind();

    public string degToCompass(double i)
    {...}

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        aTimer.Interval = 5000;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    protected void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] metingen = IcarusFTP.GetTXT();
        Icarus.Gust = Decimal.Parse(metingen[4], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Icarus.Speed = Decimal.Parse(metingen[6], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Icarus.Dir = Int32.Parse(metingen[7]);
        labelSpeed3.Text enter code here= Icarus.Speed.ToString();
        labelGust3.Text = "Gust: " + Icarus.Gust.ToString();
        labelDir3A.Text = degToCompass(Icarus.Dir);
        labelDir3B.Text = Icarus.Dir.ToString()+ "°";
    }
}
```

HTML inside a table cell:

```
<asp:label id="labelSpeed3" runat="server"></asp:label><br/>
<asp:label id="labelGust3" runat="server"></asp:label>
```

Comment: If you want the server to push updates to the client at periodic intervals then it sounds like at a high level the tool you're looking for is SignalR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `Ajax` *(not ASP.NET Ajax)* and call `WebMethod` from code-behind.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Sample.aspx.cs" 
   Inherits="AspNetWebForm.Sample" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <br />
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="CurrentDateLabel" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            setInterval(function getData() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Sample.aspx/GetCurrentDate") %>',
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        $("#<%= CurrentDateLabel.ClientID %>").text(msg.d);
                    }
                });
            }, 5000); // Post back to server via Ajax every 5 secs
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### Code Behind

```
using System;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace AspNetWebForm
{
    public partial class Sample : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                // Initialize date if you want to
                CurrentDateLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh-mm-ss");
            }
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public static string GetCurrentDate()
        {
            return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh-mm-ss"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks for the help. I now even return an array through ajax. I can now send all my values in one call. Exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

This can be best handled through AJAX call from the client side. Or if you want it to be done in the ASP.NET Webforms way - try making a  __doPostBack() call with appropriate eventArgs in the second params.

Still, AJAX would be the way to go.